# Json + javascript Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, json

```
var dat;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        dat = data;
        alert(data.name);
    }
});
```

I am trying take JSON-encoded data from URL. Here is the response that AJAX receives from the server: http://pastebin.com/53e6CgbK. However, the web browser give me an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

How can to get an attribute from the JSON encoded data?

Comment: Where do you set the `url` variable? Are the asterisks part of the code? Does it work better if you change `url: url,` to `'url': url,`?

Comment: url = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/lo,loe/?key=myBINGkey&callback=?"

Comment: Please show us the full code if you want help.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Tz0hrVWe all code, i'm trying to take a city by click, and show wiki in iframe

Comment: I could imagine that the `callback=?` parameter in the URL makes jQuery expect JSONP despite what you set as option. Or that the server returns JSONP. You have to match it. If you get JSON, remove the `callback=?` from the URL. If you get JSONP, remove it as well and set `dataType: jsonp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have a syntax error in your code prior to the $.ajax call, such as a missing '}' which makes the javascript engine get out of sync with your intentions and get unexpected ":".

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Tz0hrVWe all code, i'm trying to take a city by click, and show wiki in iframe

Answer (score 0):

You  are making a cross domain request which needs to return JSONP. Many API's do not return JSONP and the example url you gave does not.